# How do botnets deliver spam?

Tags: email, spam, botnet, email-spoofing

I can't seem to find the answer to this question.
I read that botnet bots are used as email relays (they have smtp servers installed).

Wikipedia on Open mail relay:

> "(...)Internet initiatives to close open relays have ultimately missed
>   their intended purpose because spammers have created distributed
>   botnets of zombie computers that contain malware with mail relaying
>   capability. The number of clients under spammers' control is now so
>   great that previous anti-spam countermeasures that focused on closing
>   open relays are no longer effective."

I also read that botnets are used to cover tracks and bypass black-lists of spam.This  brings me many questions:

1. Do botnets have email domains compromised?
2. How do botnets deliver email with fake source addresses?(without
   email trusted email servers compromissed)
3. Nowadays, it is hard to spam known email companies (like gmail)
   because they do not accept telnet connections and fake source
   addresses. It requires authentication. How do botnets and spammers
   deal with this?
4. If bots are relays, don't that mean that they can only deliver spam
   to other bots. Does this make any sense? This won't even affect
   users.
5. How can botnets bypass domain blacklisting if they need known
   accounts and therefore domains to send on source addresses?

I also read a pdf from this link:
https://www.damballa.com/downloads/r_pubs/WP_Botnet_Communications_Primer.pdf

It states this about domain flux:

> Domain Wildcarding abuses native DNS functionality to wildcard (e.g.,
>   *) a higher domain such that all FQDN’s point to the same IP address. For example, *.damballa.com could encapsulate both
>   mypc.atl.damballa.com and myserver.damballa.com. **This technique is
>   most commonly associated with botnets that deliver spam and phishing
>   content – whereby the wildcarded information that appears random (e.g.
>   “asdkjlkwer” of asdkjlkwer.atl.damballa) is used by the botnet
>   operator to uniquely identify a victim, track success using various
>   delivery techniques, and bypass anti-spam technologies.**

Can anyone explain me the bold sentences? Who is the victim? The compromised machine or the spam target? Ho does domain wildcarding help on spam and phishing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, some background information about how email works.  The basic issue is that server-to-server contacts using SMTP are unauthenticated: all a server knows about the computer contacting it is

1. The IP address
2. Who the computer wants to send the email to
3. Who the computer *claims* they are
4. Who the computer *claims* the email is from

Note that the last two items are not authenticated: the sending computer can lie freely about them.

Ordinary email works as follows (simplified somewhat):

1. Email client makes a connection to the sending server using authenticated SMTP or IMAP.
2. Sending server makes an unauthenticated SMTP connection to the receiving server and hands off the email.
3. Recipient makes an authenticated POP3 or IMAP connection to the receiving server and requests the email.

A spammer's botnet instead does the following:

1. Spammer contacts botnet, tells it to send spam
2. Botnet computer acts as SMTP server, makes unauthenticated SMTP connection to receiving server and hands off the email.
3. Recipient makes an authenticated POP3 or IMAP connection to the receiving server and requests the email.

To answer your questions:

1. Generally, no.
2. By lying.  The "from" address on an email is trivial to forge (as easy as forging it on a piece of physical mail).  There are various techniques to combat this: [DomainKeys Identified Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) are ways to limit which IP addresses are permitted to send email for a given domain name; an older technique was a simple reverse address lookup to see if the IP address resolved to the domain, but this has reliability issues.
3. By being careful about their lies.  If a spammer is careful about who they claim the email is from (eg. using a "from" domain that doesn't provide DKIM or SPF information), they can lie without being caught.
4. An SMTP server can accept email for local delivery, or for sending on to another server.  An SMTP server that doesn't require authentication when accepting email to send onwards is an open relay.  By this definition, bots aren't open relays -- they act more like traditional email servers, with the spammer as the only authorized user.
5. It's unclear what you're asking here.  Botnets mostly don't need known accounts to send spam.
6. This is irrelevant to spamming.  It's a technique for hiding botnet infrastructure that lets multiple domain names resolve to a single IP address.

Comment: Thanks you for your help but here you are assuming that the servers receiving spam are open relays without authentication.In 5 i talked about accounts because if you don't have a gmail account, you cannot connect to gmail server and deliver spam.So a question remains: in a scenario where there are no open relays whatsoever the only way for a spammer to deliver spam is by getting a fake account on a email provider right?

Comment: Your basic premise is wrong: any SMTP server will accept email for local delivery without authentication.  If it worked any other way, a person without a gmail account would be unable to send email to a gmail user.

Comment: Can you tell me how to deliver an email to a local gmail account trough an ssh connection?

Comment: No, because SSH is the wrong tool for the job.  I can show you how to do it by speaking SMTP using telnet (replace xxxxxxxxxxxxx with the domain you want to send from, and yyyyyyyyyyyy with the Gmail user you want to send to): http://pastebin.com/LgJ6a2jv

Comment: It does not work. That is what i am trying to say. Gmail demands ssh. Telnet does not work anymore

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding: I'm using the Telnet program as a tool to talk to Google's SMTP server on port 25, and it works: that pastebin is a transcript from 20 minutes ago.  The only other thing I can think of is that your ISP is blocking outbound connections to port 25 as an anti-spam measure.

Comment: I tried. This is strange. I was connecting to server smtp.gmail.com and i was able to connect but as soon as i wrote MAIL TO:... it asked me to STARTTLS. But when i connected to your server it worked. It's hostname included MSA so i assume it was a Mail Submission Agent. Yet, i don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I got my server from doing an MX lookup of "gmail.com" to find out what servers Google wants incoming email to be sent to.  The pastebin shows me performing "step 2" from my answer, with me taking the part of the sending server (or botnet) and gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com taking the part of the receiving server.  "smtp.google.com" isn't listed by in DNS as a mail exchanger, so presumably it's expecting you to do "step 1" from my answer, with it playing the part of the sending server.

Comment: you get the points. thank you very much for your time ;)
And one more thing.The server i used is presumably a Mail Submission Agent who demands SMTP AUTH. Maybe that is the reason why i can't send through it .

Comment: @BrunoMCBraga thnx for this question

Comment: @Mark,thanks for your answers however "can the bots send spam in a network where Outbound smtp is blocked"(not through internal mail server or triangular_spamming).